# Excell Power Query - Error "cannot apply field access to the type Text" while reformatting a string

Tags: excel, powerquery

I get the following error in Excell PowerQuery for the column "FORECAST_DATE" :

```
Expression.Error: We cannot apply field access to the type Text.
Details:
    Value=20230717 12:15:03
    Key=FORECAST_DATE
```

Here is the code :

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("file path"), null, true),
    CashForecast_Sheet = Source{[Item="CashForecast",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(CashForecast_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"DateEditing" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Promoted Headers",
        {
            {"FORECAST_DATE", each 
                let
                    datePart = Text.From([FORECAST_DATE]),
                    year = Text.Start(datePart, 4),
                    month = Text.Range(datePart, 5, 2),
                    day = Text.Range(datePart, 7, 2),
                    timePart = Text.Range(datePart, 10, 8)
                in
                    day & "/" & month & "/" & year & " " & timePart, type any
            }
        }
    )
in
    #"DateEditing"
```

I try to reformate the dateTime string (eg: 20230717 12:12:26) as "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" (eg. 17/07/2023 12:10:34) with the type "any"

Starting with Power Query, so i'm unable to explain what I tried based on the google search result.
It is a problem of access, [someone seems to have resolve it with a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62938012/power-query-date-from-yymmdd-to-dd-mm-yyyy) ?
[It maybe be due to the function used ?](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/table-transformcolumns-expression-error-we-cannot-apply-field-access-to-the-type-text.1201901/)

Comment: Something like: `Table.TransformColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{{"FORECAST_DATE", each DateTime.FromText(Date.ToText(Date.From(Text.Start(_, 8)), "dd/MM/yyyy") &  Text.End(_,9)), type date}})` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
#"DateEditing"=  Table.ReplaceValue(#"Promoted Headers",  each [FORECAST_DATE], each 
            let
               datePart = Text.From([FORECAST_DATE]),
                year = Text.Start(datePart, 4),
                month = Text.Range(datePart, 4, 2),
                day = Text.Range(datePart, 6, 2),
                timePart = Text.Range(datePart, 8, 9)
            in day & "/" & month & "/" & year & " " & timePart
,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"FORECAST_DATE"})
```

[image]